# Wrapping or Copying During User-Defined Casts

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections, casting, type-conversion

I have a custom collection class that implements `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` and actually uses `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` as the underlying storage for my custom collection.  I wanted an implicit cast to Dictionary and an explicit cast from it to my custom class.

What I'm not completely sure about is when casting *to* `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` should I be returning the underlying collection, or copy the underlying dictionary to a new object and return that value?  Likewise in the opposite direction, *from* `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, should I be wrapping the casted dictionary or copy the values into a new dictionary?

My implementation isn't immutable, but instead just adds some additional features.  I personally cannot see a problem that would arise from either method of conversion.  In this specific case a modification of the underlying collection won't cause a problem with the state of the wrapped collection.  Therefore is there a non-performance based reason to use one method over the other?

Example Class:

```
public class MyDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    ...
    public static implicit operator Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(MyDictionary<TKey, TValue> myDict)
    {
        return myDict.dictionary;
    }

   //OR

    public static implicit operator Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(MyDictionary<TKey, TValue> myDict)
    {
        return new Dictionary(myDict);
    }

    ...
}
```

PS:  I'm not looking for "best-practice" or a subjective answer.  If the answer is "NO, there is no objective non-performance backed difference in using one method or the other" that is an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from performance, the only concern is mutability.  As your implementation is not immutable, the first way is probably more correct as it allows direct mutability of the underlying dictionary.